# Haskell - Recursive function, eating a string list

Tags: string, haskell, dictionary, recursion

I'm new to haskell and trying to learn something while building a personal project.

I've defined a function:

```
pacHead :: String -> String
pacHead textrow =
   let first = head textrow
      in if first /= '"'
         then pacHead (tail textrow)
         else textrow
```

I want it to take a string, verify if it's head is a certain char (") and 'eat' the string up to the point the char is removed. Example:

IN: bla bla bla bla "citation" bla bla -> OUT: citation" bla bla

But, when I apply it to a list of strings (using map) it just returns an empty list.

```
let firstPac = map pacHead linesList
```

1. How can I fix/improve this function without using libraries ?
2. Where I can find a *good* intro about function definitions (especially recursion) with examples done over string lists instead of dummy numbers ?

Comment: Other than the use of `head` and `tail` (which do not work on empty lists), it looks OK; are you sure that `linesList` has type `[String]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fix/improve this function without using libraries ?

First notice that your function is:

```
pacHead :: String -> String
pacHead = tail . dropWhile (/= '"')

Prelude> let pacHead = tail.dropWhile (/= '"')
Prelude> pacHead "bla bla bla bla \"citation\" bla bla"
"citation\" bla bla"
```

Recursive version (with patternt matching):

```
pacHead :: String -> String
pacHead "" = ""
pacHead (x:xs) | x == '"'  = xs
               | otherwise = pacHead xs
```

You first check if the string is empty, where you return an empty string, otherwise yo pattern match the string, `x` becomes the first char and `xs` the remaining string, if x is equal to `"` you return the remaining string otherwise you continue computing the string.

> Where I can find a good about functions definitions (especially
>   recursion) with examples done over string lists instead of dummy
>   numbers ?

Almost any example about list can be applied to string, becouse string is just a `type alias` for `[char]`